# Does Sqlite3 has something like 'CREATE EVENT [IF NOT EXISTS] event_name ON SCHEDULE every 5 seconds'?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I'm using python to control a local Sqlite3 database, and I want to delete some of the rows in a table which meet certain conditions every 5 seconds while updating the table at the same time. Is there a thing like 'event' in Sqlite3? Or I can only achieve the same effect by using things like 'Timer' in my python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no task scheduler in SQLlite.

One way to do what you're looking for in Python would be to use the scheduler package:

```
import schedule

def job():
    print("do something with sqlite")

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Is there a way to do the same kind of thing from sqlite side and not from the python code.

Comment: @LakshanCosta As I wrote in the first line of my answer - AFAIK SQLite doesn't have a task scheduler. There are multiple other tools / libraries / packages that do provide scheduling and that can integrate with SQLite.